# Connecting to Centos 5 from Windows/Putty/X11 Forwarding

Tags: putty, x11-forwarding

I have a centos server with barebones X11 installed.  I am trying to connect to this server from my Windows box with Putty and Xming.

I have set X11Forwarding to yes in the sshd_config file.  I have install x11 apps and xauth.  I connect to the server with Putty with X11 forwarding enabled and pointing to localhost:0 and I have the Xming server running.

Trying to run xclock, I always get "Error: Can't open display".  Any ideas what I can check or what I am missing. I have been googling since 2h already!

P.S. I am not running an X server on the server side. I am not sure I can do this with a VPS.

Answer (score 2):

`localhost:0` is almost certainly wrong. sshd starts at `:10`, and sets `$DISPLAY` for you already.

Comment: `X11DisplayOffset 10` should be set in sshd_config?

Comment: @samyi: That is the default value.

Answer (score 1):

xclock seems buggy with new Putty & Xming versions.

I suggest you try some other command like **xlogo**, **xterm** or **xev** to test (wait at least 5s) .

If it's still not working, check the $DISPLAY env variable on the server (CentOS):

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

or

```
env | grep DISPLAY
```

UPDATE: here's a step-by-step guide:

http://ducquoc.wordpress.com/2012/09/08/putty-x11forward-xming/

Hope this helps.